# Remove extra subdir.mk include in makefile generated by Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, makefile

I have 2 configurations set up in my project, Debug and Release. Everything was set up pretty much the same across both configurations. However, after the build the makefiles generated by Eclipse are different that the Release version contains a few more lines.

This is the screenshot of the include section of makefile for Debug build: [Debug build makefile include](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcoGQ.png)

And this is the screenshot of the include section of makefile for Release build: [Release build makefile include](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIhBi.png)

As you can see, the Release version contains 2 more lines:

`-include Shaders/Fragment/subdir.mk
-include Assets/Meshes/subdir.mk`

And therefore 2 more `subdir.mk` files have been generated. I would like to get rid of those 2 includes as well as those 2 files as both of them are empty. How could I achieve this in Eclipse?

Comment: No screenshots or links to text please. Include it in your question instead.

Comment: Is creating your own `Makefile` out of the question?

Comment: @Galik Not really, I'm just curious about why it generates those extra dependencies to begin with.